# vectorize numpy unique for subarrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array data of shape (N, 20, 20) with N being some very large number.
I want to get the number of unique values in each of the 20x20 sub-arrays.
with a loop that would be:

```
values = []
for i in data:
    values.append(len(np.unique(i)))
```

How could I vectorize this loop? speed is a concern.

If I try np.unique(data) I get the unique values for the whole data array not the individual 20x20 blocks, so that's not what I need.

Comment: Have you considered writing a Fortran function for this and wrapping it with f2py? Within the fortran subroutine you can parallelize quite easily with OpenMP. I often resort to this approach when I need to speed up a computationally intensive loop.

Comment: Another approach might be to use numba http://numba.pydata.org . It has a vectorize decorator that I believe might be applicable to this case. I am not an expert on numba so you might like to take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks deepak. I don't know Fortran, I would rather try to use cython is I have to use another language. I may explore how to use numba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can work with `data.reshape(N,-1)`, since you are interested in sorting the last 2 dimensions.

An easy way to get the number of unique values for each row is to dump each row into a set and let it do the sorting:

```
[len(set(i)) for i in data.reshape(data.shape[0],-1)]
```

But this is an iteration, through probably a fast one.

A problem with 'vectorizing' is that the set or list of unique values in each row will differ in length.  'rows with differing length' is a red flag when it comes to 'vectorizing'.  You no longer have the 'rectangular' data layout that makes most vectorizing possible.

You could sort each row:

```
np.sort(data.reshape(N,-1))

array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7],
       [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 9],
       [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7, 9]])
```

But how do you identify the unique values in each row without iterating?  Counting the number of nonzero differences might just do the trick:

```
In [530]: data=np.random.randint(10,size=(5,10))

In [531]: [len(set(i)) for i in data.reshape(data.shape[0],-1)]
Out[531]: [7, 6, 6, 8, 6]

In [532]: sdata=np.sort(data,axis=1)
In [533]: (np.diff(sdata)>0).sum(axis=1)+1            
Out[533]: array([7, 6, 6, 8, 6])
```

I was going to add a warning about floats, but if `np.unique` is working for your data, my approach should work just as well.

---

```
[(np.bincount(i)>0).sum() for i in data]
```

This is an iterative solution that is clearly faster than my `len(set(i))` version, and is competitive with the `diff...sort`.

In [585]: data.shape
Out[585]: (10000, 400)

```
In [586]: timeit [(np.bincount(i)>0).sum() for i in data]
1 loops, best of 3: 248 ms per loop

In [587]: %%timeit                                       
sdata=np.sort(data,axis=1)
(np.diff(sdata)>0).sum(axis=1)+1
   .....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 280 ms per loop
```

I just found a faster way to use `bincount`, `np.count_nonzero`

```
In [715]: timeit np.array([np.count_nonzero(np.bincount(i)) for i in data])
10 loops, best of 3: 59.6 ms per loop
```

I was surprised at the speed improvement.  But then I recalled that `count_nonzero` is used in other functions (e.g. `np.nonzero`) to allocate space for their return results.  So it makes sense that this function would be coded for maximum speed.  (It doesn't help in the `diff...sort` case because it does not take an axis parameter).

Comment: Thanks. It does work! Although I was hoping to get it to run faster. On my data is taking about 7s and I'd like to get it done in less than a 1s. If there isn't another answer with a faster method I'll accept yours.

Comment: So 'vectorize' is really code for 'fastest'?  :)  `np.sort` takes about 3/4 of the time; the `diff` part only 1/4.  `sort` by row takes just as long as sorting the whole flattened array.

Comment: I found a `bincount` version that's slightly faster - but it iterates by row.

Comment: I tried the bincount version, and when I adapt it to my script it's actually slower (~11s) that the sort/diff (~7s), I need to place the results in specific parts of a numpy array, I not sure if that take much time. In any case I think the sort/diff version is probably as fast as it can get with pure python. So I accept the answer. I'm going to try cython as I need this to work in less than a second.

Comment: I found that `count_nonzero` can speed up the `bincount` solution quite a bit.

Comment: using the count_nonzero with the bitcount solution it went from (~11s) to (~7s), similar time to the diff/sort solution.