# How to turn Numpy array to set efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, set

I used:

```
df['ids'] = df['ids'].values.astype(set)
```

to turn `lists` into `sets`, but the output was a list not a set:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 2.5],[12,35,12]])

>>> x.astype(set)
array([[1.0, 2.0, 2.5],
       [12.0, 35.0, 12.0]], dtype=object)
```

Is there an efficient way to turn list into set in `Numpy`?

**EDIT 1:**
My input is as big as below:
I have 3,000 records. Each has 30,000 ids: [[1,...,12,13,...,30000], [1,..,43,45,...,30000],...,[...]]

Comment: @AlirezaHos it doesn't seem to me that processing `x = np.array([[1, 2, 2.5],[12,35,12]])` should take 19 seconds with *any* method. Care to elaborate?

Comment: `astype(set)` does not do what you think.  There isn't a `numpy` set `dtype`.  So it just returns an `object` array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current state of your question (can change any time): how can I efficiently remove duplicate elements from a large array of large arrays?

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
arr = rng.random((3000, 30000))
out1 = list(map(np.unique, arr))
#or
out2 = [np.unique(subarr) for subarr in arr]
```

Runtimes in an IPython shell:

```
>>> %timeit list(map(np.unique, arr))
5.39 s ± 37.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit [np.unique(subarr) for subarr in arr]
5.42 s ± 58.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

**Update**: as [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196102/how-to-turn-numpy-array-to-set-efficiently/33197029?noredirect=1#comment54210195_33197029) pointed out in his comment, my dummy example is biased since floating-point random numbers will almost certainly be unique. So here's a more life-like example with integer numbers:

```
>>> arr = rng.integers(low=1, high=15000, size=(3000, 30000))

>>> %timeit list(map(np.unique, arr))
4.98 s ± 83.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit [np.unique(subarr) for subarr in arr]
4.95 s ± 51.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In this case the elements of the output list have varying lengths, since there are actual duplicates to remove.

Comment: Should not the problem be stated as "keep unique elements" or "remove duplicates" rather than "remove unique"?

Answer (score 31):

First flatten your ndarray to obtain a single dimensional array, then apply set() on it:

```
set(x.flatten())
```

Edit : since it seems you just want an array of set, not a set of the whole array, then you can do `value = [set(v) for v in x]` to obtain a list of sets.

Comment: I don't want to merge lists into one. I want to turn each individually into a set

Comment: value = [set(v) for v in x], then ?

Comment: As I said I'm looking for an efficient way. Your second solution isn't the best way. For my case it takes around 19 seconds.

Comment: @AlirezaHos any reason to believe this solution is not efficient? How much data is processed in 19 seconds? 10 elements? 100? 10^10? And any reason for *not including your complete problem in the original question*?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I have 3,000 records. Each has 30,000 ids: `[[1,...,12,13,...,30000], [1,..,43,45,...,30000]]`

Comment: @AlirezaHos Any specific to convert all of that data into sets? Storing as numpy arrays must be pretty efficient.

Comment: @Divakar, I want to remove duplicates and merge them.

Comment: @Divakar especially that converting to sets should involve going over each element and checking for multiplicities and sorting. No wonder it's slow:)

Comment: @AlirezaHos check out `np.unique(v)` or maybe a list comprehension doing this. Or `map`, but I haven't looked at that yet.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, what do you suggest for my case in order to remove duplicate elements. Moreover I in some cases I use `groupby` in `pandas` and I want to merge them after groupby without any duplicates. for now I use `set.union` to merge those sets into one set.

Comment: @AlirezaHos a question which leads to 10 comments is generally the sign that information was missing in the original post. Please take note for your future posts.

Comment: `set(x.ravel())` should be more efficient because it doesn't make a copy.  (Actually `set(x.flat)` is even better.)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of earlier 'row-wise' unique questions:

[vectorize numpy unique for subarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379895/vectorize-numpy-unique-for-subarrays)

[Numpy: Row Wise Unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958233/numpy-row-wise-unique-elements)

[Count unique elements row wise in an ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789014/count-unique-elements-row-wise-in-an-ndarray)

In a couple of these the count is more interesting than the actual unique values.

If the number of unique values per row differs, then the result cannot be a (2d) array.  That's a pretty good indication that the problem cannot be fully vectorized.  You need some sort of iteration over the rows.

Comment: @fabrik, those are SO links, in a 3 yr old answer.  By your logic we couldn't mark posts as duplicates without repeating the old answers.